# Predicates and Quantifiers in discrete math

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Let P(x,y) be "x is waiting for y", where the universe of discourse is the set of all people in the world. Use quantifiers to express the following statement.
(i)There is no one who is waiting for everybody.
(ii) Everybody is waiting for somebody.

May i know how to solve this kind of question?

Comment: *Everybody* must be translated with the *universal* quantifier : $\forall$ (for all), while "somebody" must be translated with the *existential* quantifier : $\exists$ (exists).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA for the part (ii) is the answer is ∀x{∃y P(x,y))?

Comment: Yes, it's right ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA how about the part(i)?

Comment: how to do it with "no one"?

Comment: If "there is one" is $\exists$ (exists), "no one" should be $\lnot \exists$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20068/discussion-between-bilis-and-mauro-allegranza).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach it as follows:

**(i)** "There is no one who is waiting for everybody." **Meaning:** There does not exist a person (i.e., $\nexists x$) who is waiting for everybody (i.e., $\forall y$). Thus, for (i), we get the following: $\nexists x \forall y P(x,y)$. However, you may want to report the answer without any negated quantifiers; in such a case, you may observe the following:
$$
\neg(\nexists x \forall y P(x,y)) = (\neg \nexists x)(\exists y)\neg P(x,y) = \exists x \exists y \neg P(x,y),
$$
where $\neg P(x,y)$ is taken to mean "$x$ is not waiting for $y$."

**(ii)** "Everybody is waiting for somebody." **Meaning:** There exists someone (i.e., $\exists y$) who is being waited for by everyone (i.e., $\forall x$). Thus, the reported answer for (ii) would be $\exists y \forall x P(x,y)$. Note that the order of quantifiers is important here.

This is how I would answer it anyway.

Comment: @Bilis Does that answer your question?

Comment: so it is no problem for me if i write ∀x(∃y P(x,y)) for (ii)?

Comment: yes of course ^^ thanks

Comment: @Bilis Then you may want to indicate that your question has been answered rather than just upvoting my response (that way others know what you asked for has been reported and you are satisfied).

Comment: how can i indicate it?sorry

Comment: @Bilis No worries. Simply click the green check arrow under the downvote arrow.